# wordpress attaching gallery photos to new post by coding

Tags: wordpress, gallery, attachment

I am doing a migration of articles from drupal to wordrepss, there are articles with gallery, I have not yet found how to link a gallery of multiple photos to an article

Can you please help me pass this step

Here is my code :

```
.....
$my_post        //A table that I filled with the necessary elements
$post_id        =   wp_insert_post( $my_post );

// Create the attachment of main photo
// Set attachment data
$attachment = array(
                    'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
                    'post_title'     => sanitize_file_name( $filename ),
                    'post_content'   => '',
                    'post_status'    => 'inherit'
                );
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $post_id );

//insertion of photo gallery
set_post_format($post_id, 'gallery' );
for($n=1;$n<=$NbrImgGallery;$n++){
       $my_post_gallery['post_title']       =   "Titre photo-".$n;
        $my_post_gallery['post_content']    =   "Description photo-".$n;
        $my_post_gallery['post_status']     =   'publish';
        $my_post_gallery['post_author']     =   1;      
        $my_post_gallery['post_type']       =   "attachment";
        $my_post_gallery['post_parent']     =   $post_id;
        $Gallery_post_id        =   wp_insert_post( $my_post_gallery );
}
```

Comment: What is the question?  Be clear.

Comment: thank you for your reply
I want to create a gallery (multiple photos) and attach it to an article

Comment: Do you know how a gallery is created in WP? Meaning - do you know what you are asking for? What the data should look like? Etc?

Comment: Maybe it's not the right term , But what I want is to create an article that will contain a title, desc, categorie, ... and a multiple of images